# Is there any GUI tool for setting up an OpenVPN server?

Tags: gui, openvpn

It's really painful to do it in CLI, there are so many commands and parameters that I can not fully understand and remember, but I still need to set up the OpenVPN server, is there any way to do it in GUI? Any GUI tool to do it easily?

Comment: Not that I know of, but there are a few automated scripts that take the pain out of manual configuration (e.g., https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install).

Answer (score 3):

OpenVPN Access Server have good web gui interface. Simply to install. But have free license only for 2 clients.
[OpenVPN Access Server](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw.html)
Also you can look at this project https://github.com/deranjer/OpenVPN-PHP-Management-Gui
And look plugins to webmin panel.

Comment: PHP Plugin is Deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using OpenVPN Acess Server, the easiest way to install and manage OpenVPN is with a shell script such as the one I made (based off another script by Nyr)which you can get [here](https://github.com/NerdOfLinux/Scripts). Although it doesn't have a GUI, it still has a easy to use interface.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)